# How to compare comma separated values in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.
users(id,name)
items(id,name,price) and
orders(id,user_id,item_id)

Here my item_id column has comma separated values like `[1,2,3]`. I have below query which works perfectly if item_id has single value.

```
select users.name,items.price
from orders
join users
on user.id = orders.user_id
join items
on items.id =  orders.item_id
where orders.id = 1
```

Can any one suggest me how can i get the same result as in above query when there are comma separated values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `find_in_set` function:

```
select users.name,items.price
from orders
join users
on user.id = orders.user_id
join items
on find_in_set(items.id, orders.item_id)
where orders.id = 1
```

However, store `id` with comma separated is a kind of bad db design, you'd better add a table to store the relationship between `orders` and `items`.

Just take an example：

```
create table order_item (
    order_id varchar(20),
    item_id varchar(20)
);
```

then the query:

```
select users.name,items.price
from orders
join users
on user.id = orders.user_id
join order_item oi on oi.order_id = orders.id
join items on oi.item_id = items.id
where orders.id = 1
group by orders.id
```

***EDIT***:

With `[]` included, you can try this:

```
select users.name,items.price
from orders
join users
on user.id = orders.user_id
join items
on find_in_set(items.id, replace(replace(orders.item_id, '[', ''), ']', ''))
where orders.id = 1
```

Comment: Please suggest better design. I am storing entire id array.

Comment: thanks for suggesting better design. I tried query with find_in_set but didn't get any result. I will implement your suggestion later on but now i want to get the result from what i have now.

Comment: My db field has value "[1,2,3]", note that it has both square bracket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)